# ESP32 TCP client

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, micropython, esp32

I want to set up TCP server on windows and TCP client on ESP32. Main idea is to send String to ESP32 change it and send it back to server, but I'm really new with all of this stuff and got stuck on setting up TCP client on ESP32. Examples or references would be really helpful.

Comment: This question is much too broad and unspecific for this site. Assuming you want to use Micropython on the ESP32, you could try asking on the Micropython forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int create_ipv4_socket()
{
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *res;
  struct in_addr *addr;

  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

  int err = getaddrinfo(UDP_IPV4_ADDR, TCP_PORT, &hints, &res);

  if(err != 0 || res == NULL) {
    printf("DNS lookup failed err=%d res=%p\n", err, res);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Code to print the resolved IP.

     Note: inet_ntoa is non-reentrant, look at ipaddr_ntoa_r for "real" code */
  addr = &((struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
  printf("DNS lookup succeeded. IP=%s\n", inet_ntoa(*addr));

  l_sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, 0);
  if(l_sock < 0) {
    printf("... Failed to allocate socket.\n");
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return -1;
  }

  struct timeval to;
  to.tv_sec = 2;
  to.tv_usec = 0;
  setsockopt(l_sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,&to,sizeof(to));

  if(connect(l_sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) != 0) {
    printf("... socket connect failed errno=%d\n", errno);
    close(l_sock);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return -1;
  }

  printf("... connected\n");
  freeaddrinfo(res);

  // All set, socket is configured for sending and receiving
  return l_sock;
}
```

From this forum https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=5965

Comment: Please add a description of how your proposal answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

How do you communicate with your ESP? if you communicate through UART, just send him AT command he need by writing on the UART port:

"AT+CIPSTATUS\r\n"
and then wait for his response.

If you are connected to your ESP32 directly with your computer, just use putty and directly send AT command to it.

A non exhaustive list of AT's command can be found here:
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_at_instruction_set_and_examples_en.pdf